# add virtual drives (raid) without needing to reboot dell h700

Tags: raid, dell, dell-poweredge

Is it possible to add a virtual drive without needing to reboot the computer?

Or actually what I really want, is some way to just pop in harddrives (using the hotswaps  in the backplane), and start using the harddrives.
That is, making the h700 work as a simple disc controller similar to what we could do on a poweredge 2900.

But I dont think this is possible, so the second best solution would be,
to be able to make a vd without having to reboot.

I am currently using ubuntu and has installed the openmanage software
http://linux.dell.com/repo/community/deb/

This lets me see the configuration of the raid system, but wont let me change anything.

Thanks
edit:
I just want to add a new harddrive to our system, without having to reboot.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here, from a functional perspective? it's hard to work out what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the edit, have you considered just using a USB drive? they're inherently hot-plu/unpluggable and if you have a USB3 model it should be broadly as quick as an eSATA or SAS model.

Comment: No this doesnt really apply in my case, we receive 5 new disk a month with data we want to analyse. So hotswapping using the frontbay is what we want

Answer (score 0):

`omconfig` should give you a full cli set to create vdisks at your will - from what I read about omsa 6.5 ubuntu support.